# Issues with Pandas and Numpy Version

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, installation, conflict

I think have a whole mess of conflicts.  I was attempting to run some code in a notebook and got the following message:

> ImportError: this version of pandas is incompatible with numpy < 1.16.5
> your numpy version is 1.16.2.
> Please upgrade numpy to >= 1.16.5 to use this pandas version

I have version 1.2.2 of pandas installed.

I ran `conda update numpy` and still got the same error when I tried to run the notebook.  I ran `conda list` and it says my version is 1.20.0 but if I run:

```
import numpy
print(numpy.version.version)
```

It says my version is 1.16.2.  Running `pip list` it says my version is 1.16.2.  I tried to force an upgrade by using `pip install -Iv numpy==1.20.0 --force-reinstall` and it returned the following error at the end of the install:

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
> target-encoding 0.5.0 requires numpy==1.16.2, but you have numpy 1.20.0 which is incompatible.
> Successfully installed numpy-1.20.1

Yet it still says that my version is 1.16.2 and that pandas is still incompatible with numpy.

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me to resolve this quagmire.

Comment: Did `conda update numpy` ran into any errors or warnings?

Comment: No issues with conda.

Comment: Do you have multiple environments and did you run `numpy.version.version` at the same place where you ran `conda update numpy`?

Comment: I do have two environments but I only really use one of them.  Everything I wrote about was done in that environment.

Comment: You have got conda, that means you use anaconda environment and pandas, numpy etc are preinstalled. Still getting this warning, strange. You can try completely deleting both numpy and pandas and then installing again. **NOTE** `conda uninstall pkg` or `pip uninstall pkg` does not remove the package completely.

Comment: Could you solve this problem @Jerel

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Solved by reinstalling numpy a few times subsequently, until there is not any version of it installed. And then install again the version I needed.

Comment: What method(s) did you use to reinstall?  Did you just keep repeating the same method?  How many tries did it take.  I have tried repeating the install but I kept having the same results.

Comment: Hi, Jerel. Iám using VSCode + Anaconda. I've got the messages after installing tensorflow. I've used conda uninstall pandas + conda uninstall numpy, then checked in conda list if any version of this packages is still there. I've tried these steps in the base environment and also in my virtual environment. You could also look for a message of inconsistencies in your environment, by running conda update --all. Good luck!